# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. in Laravel 7 and AJAX

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to insert data using Ajax in Laravel 7. Everytime i click on Submit button, it displays the error.  `The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.`

When i empty the `method=""` in form, nothing happens. I also tried to override the method by writing `@method=''` after `Form` but also it didn't work

This is my form in blade view.

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="btn-submit">
    @csrf
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="sendBtn">Submit</button>
    </span>
</form>
```

This is my Route

```
Route::post('/subscription', [App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController::class, 'storeSubscription'])
    ->name('subscription');
```

This is my ajax portion in layout

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $("body").on("click","#sendBtn" function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var email = $("input[name=email]").val();
        var url = '{{ route('subscription') }}';

        $.ajax({
           url:url,
           method: "POST",
           data:{
                  Code:email, 
                },
           success:function(response){
              if(response.success){
                  alert(response.message) //Message come from controller
              }else{
                  alert("Error")
              }
           },
           error:function(error){
              console.log(error)
           }
        });
    });

</script>
```

And this is my controller

```
public function storeSubscription(Request $request)
{
    DB::table('subscriptions')->insert([
        'email' => $request->Code, //This Code coming from ajax request
    ]);

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'Data inserted successfully'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to check what is going wrong? Is the AJAX call even used to submit the form? What does your browser's network console tell you about the request?

Answer (score 0):

Don't listen for the click event on the submit button as the form is being submitted without interruption, instead, listen for the form submission event like this:

```
$("body").on("submit", ".btn-submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var email = $("input[name=email]").val();
    var url = "{{ route('subscription') }}";

    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        method: "POST",
        data:{
            Code:email, 
        },
        success:function(response){
            if(response.success){
                alert(response.message) //Message come from controller
            }else{
                alert("Error")
            }
        },
        error:function(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: No sir, I did as you suggested but didn't solve my issue

Comment: A comma was missing in my answer here : $("body").on("submit", ".btn-submit", function(e)

Comment: Just rectified it. Try it now, and in case not working again, tell me of any specific error happening

Comment: Console says `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/index       405 (Method Not Allowed)` while submitting form

Comment: So based on the error in console, the URL you are producing in not correct, and it's because of single quotations you use in ajax. Here I rectified that section in my answer. Try it again.

Comment: Is your Javascript code in blade file or JS file?

Comment: It's in blade file.

Answer (score 0):

change route as per method use in form or in postman for API

```
$router->post('route/url','ControllerName@functionName');
<form method="post">
@csrf
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the route name like this:

```
var url = "@php echo route('subscription') @endphp";
```

If it still doesnt work, make sure the route name is correct, you can do it by running *php artisan r:l* in terminal and it should print out the routes name.